Man raised by immortals to kill them
Can you help identify this movie?  I saw it in the 1970's or 1980's, I believe on TV.
A civilization somehow became immortal.  It turns out they didn't like it.  So several of them "raised" a killer through many generations of selection with they intent that he kills them.
The killer was (a bandit?) on horseback.
Some (possibly incorrect) notes:

I've always thought this starred Sean Connery.
There was a moment in the movie that he realized that everyone (including those who knew how they became immortal) were still alive.  

Sorry, not much to go on.

is it possible you are confusing the Sean Connery presence with Highlander?

Maybe you're confusing Sean Connery's first science fiction motion picture, the epic masterpiece that is Zardoz. IMDb here as well. Aaaaand here is a trailer for it.
There are immortals in that, although many of your other memories don't really match. Perhaps you've mentally joined two films? There are some really (really, really really) memorable scenes in it, such as the giant floating head, so if this is it, you'll know it.
(Every time I see this flick (yes, I've watched it more than once) I find myself asking just what the hell Connery was doing in it, considering his immense world wide popularity as Bond.)

"I find myself asking just what the hell Connery was doing in it..." You mean other than wearing an orange diaper?

I'm very impressed.  I've made it through most of the film.  I recognized enough of it to confirm that Zardoz is the movie.  It is for sure worth this second watch.  Thanks.
